# After installing Xamarin.Forms.Maps in release mode I get "java.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, proguard

I have added Xamarin.Forms.Maps nugget package in my project, and everything works fine in the debug mode. But when I switch to release, if proguard is enabled I get the error "java.exe" exited with code 1.

Also, I get a lot of warnings in the output window like "warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy: can't find referenced class".

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: update progaurd to latest version

Comment: Could you please set `Tools->options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity and log file verbosity set to detailed` and provide the detailed error log?